# Init an associative array in php with object values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having difficulty initialising an associative array in PHP with custom object values. For example:

```
public $basket = [
    A => new Product("d", 2, 2)
]; // incorrect variant, interpretation error

public $basket = [
    "A" => "B", "C" => "d"
]; // correct variant
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: provide more info what you want to do

Comment: @piotr, I want init the associable array with values, which are the custom objects, as a  "Product", how in my examples above, if it's possible

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: @pragmus if the array is a class property, you can't initialize an object at the point where you declare it. You'll need to assign it somewhere, e.g. in your class's `__construct` method

Comment: (`associable array` looks weird enough to fit perfectly into PHP - I'm afraid it should read _associative_.)

Comment: @greybeard, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've initialized the object, in construct method, as Robbie Averill adviced and problem was resolved.